# Rails model singular format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

This is more a question to see if an error has occurred when creating a model in my app.

I have created a model in the usual way

```
rails g model Media
```

Now i thought that this would actually create the following

```
 class CreateMedias < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :medias do |t|
       t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

but it didnt it created

```
  class CreateMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :media do |t|
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

I thought the model represented as single media but the database consists of many medias. Why would the migration not change to medias? Is it best to delete this model and try it again or is this normal behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Media](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/media#Noun_2) is the plural of Medium.

The clean way would be to have a *Medium* model and *Media* for table name.

Comment: so change the name of the model in this case?

Comment: then the model file shouldn't be `medium.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

Media as data type is not countable. So you could add inflections.
Just put further code into your `config/initializers/inflection.rb`

`ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable 'media'
end`

[see docks here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections)